# How to loop sequentially through images in one folder and compare with the latest image in another folder

Tags: shell-script, zsh, imagemagick

I am trying to use the shell to loop sequentially through images in one folder and compare with the latest image in another folder.

One error i'm getting is -

```
zsh: no matches found: /TiffOut/*.tiff(.om[1])
```

Though I wouldn't be surprised if thats not the only problem.

What I'm hoping to acheive is:

- Loop through all source images in current directory:
- Put most recent file from TiffOut subdirectory in variable 'latest'
- Compare current source, and latest output with '-evaluate-sequence max' to  create new tiff with the brightest parts from each image_file
- Save to TiffOut subdirectory

Heres my full script -

```
#! /bin/zsh -
filelist=$(ls | grep '.tiff')
for image_file in $filelist
do
latest=$(/TiffOut/*.tiff(.om[1]))
magick $image_file $latest -evaluate-sequence Max '/TiffOut/out_${imagefile}.tiff'
done
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you think your script is doing because it isn't very clear. You're right that there are errors in the script, but we need to know what you expect it to do in order to help you get it right.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added some info

Answer (score 0):

You need to remote the leading `/` from `/TiffOut/`.

- `TiffOut/` is a relative path referring to a subdir of the present working dir, but
- `/TiffOut/` is an *absolute* path referring to a subdir of `/`, which is the root of the dir hierarchy.